# 3d flipping/rotation in flex-actionscript 3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, 3d

I want to make an flipping card object which has three sides, basic requirement is like below

[image: card flip]

as in image, I want to rotate from horizontal center of card but I can not find any way to change orientation of rotation except put card in an container and set its **x to -(width/2)** I am using **appendRotation** method after setting its z component to 1 and everytime appending -5 rotation on Y axis.

How to achieve this elegantly? any suggestions appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple two sided 3D object using the native 3D capabilities of the Flash Player, check out this handy class: http://blog.soulwire.co.uk/code/open-source/two-sided-planes-in-flash-player-10

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at [Papervision 3d](http://blog.papervision3d.org/) or [away 3D](http://www.away3d.com/) and make a 2 sided plane, one side of the plane being a view stack that contains views 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks quoo, but, I am not using papervision 3d and away 3d, thinking to achieve this using flash player 10 3d apis

Comment: The Flash Player 10 3D api's aren't very fleshed out and are really meant for very simple transitions and to support the third party 3d API's. So I think your solution is best, if you're restricted to using the built in 3D. Or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: yes, I'm restricted to use only built in 3D APIs, but this seems to have lot of limitations and so lot of problems...